# How does web server detect Content-Type for a response document?

Tags: jquery, ajax, xhtml, content-type

I have 2 identical xhtml-documents which are in **html (1st)** and **xhtml (2nd)** extensions. The difference is in extension only.

Using ajax (jQuery 1.4.1) I try to get **1st**, but web server (IIS 5.1) sends response with `Content-Type: text/html` instead of `application/xhtml+xml`. If I try to get **2nd**, there are no problems.

For both documents I use $.ajax( {...} ), but I get an error for **1st** (in the comments):

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: url, 
  dataType: 'xml', 
  contentType: 'application/xhtml+xml', 
  success: function(data, ts, theXhr) { ... },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // textStatus = "parsererror"
    // errorThrown.lineNumber = 5193
    // errorThrown.message = "data is null"
    // errorThrown.name = "TypeError"
  }
});
```

### ---

How to make [any] web server think that the **1st** document is a real xhtml?

Comment: Please note we have two different questions here. Server content-type auto-detection is an interesting subject by itself but your application should not rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the 1st document well formed etc? Parse error could mean invalid xml.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK IIS uses file extensions to detect the content-type. You can see the MIME-Type map in the IIS configuration page.

Comment: The server can be not only IIS.

Comment: MIME-Type mapping is server specific. I don't know how other servers detect the MIME-Type

Answer (score 0):

> How to make [any] web server think
>   that the 1st document is a real xhtml?

From javascript the answer is: You can't. The webserver makes the decision as to what Content-Type to send.

**If you control the server:**
You can configure IIS to send the correct Content-Type

**If you don't control the server:** There's not much you can do besides using a server-sided script to get the page and send the correct header.

How to add content-types in IIS 5.0 (from [msdn](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742440.aspx#EEAA)):

> **Adding MIME Types to IIS 5.0**
>
> MIME types can be registered in IIS
>   5.0 using the IIS snap-in.
>
> For example, to add the XML MIME type
>   to the default Web site using the IIS
>   snap-in:
>
> 1. Select Default Web Site and bring up
>      the Properties dialog box.
> 2. Select the HTTP Headers tab.
> 3. Under MIME Map, click the File Types
>      tab and select New Type.
> 4. Type .xml in the Extension field and
>      text/xml in the Content Type field,
>      and then click OK.
>
> **To add the XML MIME type to all sites running on a given machine:**
>
> 1. Select Internet Information Services
>      and bring up the Properties dialog
>      box.
> 2. Under Computer MIME Map, click the
>      Edit button and select New Type.
> 3. Type .xml in the Extension field and
>      text/xml in the Content Type field,
>      and then click OK.
>
> Any other extensions, such as .xsl
>   (eXtensible Style Sheets), may be
>   added using the same procedures.

Just change `.xml` and `text/html` with the extensions/content-type you want

Comment: I am just interested in getting `application/xhtml+xml`. Is it possible do something in jQuery to trick the header before success processing?

Comment: The error is probably thrown by the XmlHttpRequest so I don't think that's viable. I'd recommend either using the correct extension or adding a custom rule that maps `.html` to `application/xhtml+xml`

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'll map extensions for the rest kind of files if I have access to web server. It's an idea, but the problem as I could guess is somewhere in jQuery.